# Background jobs in .NET Core on Linux

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I am developing a .NET Core web API, I have an action to upload an excel file, this should read the file, process it and save the content to a SQL Server Data Base, of course one line of the excel could be inserted in multiple tables, there is table structure previously created to store all data, this is not a simple Dump or Batch process.

Besides the API, we developed an Angular 4 App for the client, so the file is uploaded from an Angular component, every thing fine so far

The problem is, someone could upload a very huge file to the API, we are thinking of a way to process the file in a background process, thus the client user will just select the file and hit **Upload File**, the API should queue the file and a background task will process the file and do what needs to be done to save to the data base.

All the infrastructure (API, Client and DB) will be deployed to a linux environment. The question is: **Is this a good approach?** **Is there something in linux to work with this?**

I've read about RabbitMQ, but I'm unsure about it or if there is something *better* or more appropiate for this kind of scenarios.

**How would you guys handle a similar scenario?**

Thanks for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) as the background job processor.

Hangfire supports RabbitMQ as well.

Or you can create your own infra tool to do this. Just follow what Hangfire or Quartz does.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug:

You can run background jobs on your Linux environment (or any other environment) with [Runly](https://www.runly.io/). It gives you things like parallel processing and [retries built-in](https://www.runly.io/docs/fault-tolerance/).

We built it for exactly the kinds of scenarios you are describing: easily breaking out long-running tasks to a background job.

Here is an [example process to import a CSV file](https://github.com/runlyio/examples/blob/master/getting-started/Census/PlaceImporter.cs).